# usb externo camara android studio

Tags: android, cámara

Buenas estoy intentando lanzar un intent para visualizar una cámara externa mediante usb, la cosa es que no doy con la tecla,ya que todo lo relacionado que he encontrado es sobre la cámara propia del móvil..mi pregunta es si hay alguna forma de la lanzar la cámara externa a traves del puerto usb,gracias

Hola de nuevo he conseguido abrir las dos cámaras del móvil y guardar las fotos,sobre el usb externo con cámara he conseguido que reconozca el usb pero no se como decirle que es una cámara y que sea la que use.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //mInfo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    cameraButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_image);
    gallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_gallery);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);

    mLogger = new Logger(this);
    mLogger.setMode(Logger.MODE_TOAST);

    mUsbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
    usbConnection();
    mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
    registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);

    mUsbManager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);

    UsbInterface intf = device.getInterface(0);
    UsbEndpoint endpoint = intf.getEndpoint(0);
    UsbDeviceConnection connection = mUsbManager.openDevice(device);
    connection.claimInterface(intf, forceClaim);
    //creo que falla aquí abajo,en bytes, como podría hacerlo en otro hilo?
    connection.bulkTransfer(endpoint,bytes, bytes.length, TIMEOUT);//do in another thread

    mLogger.log("usb", "//////////////////////////////////////: " + mCameraId);

    // Servicio USB --> Definirlo como Cámara (Añadir Cámara)
    //CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) mUsbManager;


    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
    String[] cameraList = manager.getCameraIdList();
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }


    if (manager != null) {
    try {
    for (String mCameraId : manager.getCameraIdList()) {
    CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraId);
    mLogger.log("usb", "//////////////////////////////////////: " + mCameraId);

    manager.openCamera(mCameraId, mStateCallback, null);
    }

    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    cameraButton.setEnabled(false);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta ahora? Por favor comparte el código que lleves y los errores/problemas concretos con los que te estés encontrado.

Comment: añade mas información, diagrama fotos por que realmente no se entiende

Comment: @FuriosoJack no se entiende? Yo entendi perfectamente que el usuario quiere acceder a una camara conectada mediante USB al dispositivo. Lo que no es bueno es que no haya dejado codigo, que ha intentado, que ha leido, etc